# Filter out words after divider in a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, variables, replace, split

I have a variable which for example returns: `+category1+author3`

In my HTML I have 2 links: one with `class="category1"` and one with `class="author3"`.

I want to hide both links (with for example $("a.category1").fadeOut(); ), but therefore I need to filter the words `category1` and `author3` out of the variable above. So I want to remove the divider `+` and let the code read that after every `+` comes a new word, which I want to use as a class in the further code.

So basically I want to get this `+category1+author3` to two variables `category1` and `author3` with the `+` as divider using Javascript (there also can be 1 ore 3 or 4 words in the variable, like: +category1+category4+author3+genre2).

Comment: Have a look at string.split().. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a string.split method on +

```
var s="+category1+author3";
classSplit=s.split("+"); //This will be an array
console.log(classSplit[1]) //category1
console.log(classSplit[2]) //author3
//console.log(classSplit[0]) This will be blank/null as there is nothing before+
```

EDIT:

```
 for(i=1;i< classSplit.length;i++) {//Start with 1 as 0 is null
 $classSplit[i].fadeOut();
 }
```

Comment: thank you, it almost works! But for example there can be up to 20 classes. How can you that that the script does automate do .fadeOut(); for each single classSplit?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var classSelector = "+category1+author3".split("+").join(",.");

$( classSelector ).fadeOut();
```

or

```
var classSelector = "+category1+author3".replace(/\+/g, ", .");

$( classSelector ).fadeOut();
```